# WooCommerce cart page returns empty if user is not logged in

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am in a serious problem about the cart page. I can do everything when I am logged in. But if I am not logged in , I can add products to cart , success message is there BUT the cart returns empty.

I tried a few solutions. What I have done so far is:

```
// Hook after add to cart Added by Atiqur
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart' , 'repair_woocommerce_2_2_8_session_add_to_cart');

function repair_woocommerce_2_2_8_session_add_to_cart( ){
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
        wc_setcookie( 'woocommerce_items_in_cart', 1 );
        wc_setcookie( 'woocommerce_cart_hash', md5( json_encode( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) ) );
        do_action( 'woocommerce_set_cart_cookies', true );
    }
}
```

Your help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site was hosted on **WP Engine**. It was a problem of caching. I asked them to disable caching on the shop and other product pages. Once they did , the problem was solved.